# Highchart Pie-Donut Chart Outer Y Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

In the Highcharts Pie-Donut demo (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/), the value for Y in the data set is larger than the sum of the values in the inner data set. For example:

```
data = [{
        y: 55.11,
        color: colors[0],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'MSIE versions',
            categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
            data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
            color: colors[0]
        }
    }
```

The y value is 55.11 and the sum of the inner data set is 54.07. I know that the y value is used for the outer donut and the inner data set is for the pie.

Why is the y value larger than the sum of the inner data set? Is there a formula to calculate what that y value should be?

Comment: Because MSIE are not only versions 6-9, but also 10 & 11, which are not included in the drilldown. This is just a demo to create such donut chart, no magic there.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle example the only Y that is larger then the sum of the data is Proprietary or Undetectable which has a Y of .2 and no data. No rest add up to the Y. Using the same fiddle and the same browser you showed this is the actual data:

```
{
        y: 56.33,
        color: colors[0],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'MSIE versions',
            categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0', 'MSIE 10.0', 'MSIE 11.0'],
            data: [1.06, 0.5, 17.2, 8.11, 5.33, 24.13],
            color: colors[0]
        }
    }
```

And the data adds up to the Y value.

Comment: That's really strange. The data set for the demo chart http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut is different. Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L5Lrz31e/